# Return True if any and all of the bools are True. Leave out the false ones

Tags: c#, logic

I have Three bools and cant figure out how to execute the code in each of the true ones before exiting the method. 
If I use the
`if() else if() else ()` it wont work because it will still only execute one of them. I cant figure out how else to do it. 
Basically what i want to do is execute the code in any and all of the if statements where the statement becomes true before moving on.

Example:

If bools 2 & 3 are true, but 1 is not then I firstly want to execute the code in the if statements for bools 2 & 3 before returning true.

If bools 1 & 3 are true, but 2 is not then I firstly want to execute the code in the if statements for bools 1 & 2 before returning true.

Code Below:

```
            if (bool1)
            {
                Execute My Code part 1
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (bool2)
            {
                Execute My Code part 2
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (bool3)
            {
                Execute My Code part 3
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Remove all the `else` blocks and `return` statements, and then `return bool1 || bool2 || bool3;` at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
bool flagged = false;
if (bool1)
{
    flagged = true;
    Execute Code here
}
if (bool2)
{
    flagged = true;
    Execute Code here
}
if (bool3)
{
    flagged = true;
    Execute Code here
}
return flagged;
```

Answer (score 5):

another try:

```
if (bool1)
    execute_bool1();
if (bool2)
    execute_bool2();
if (bool3)
    execute_bool3();

return (bool1 || bool2 || bool3);
```

Comment: simpler.. i like it

Comment: probably personal taste but I like this variant the best, it feels clean somehow

Answer (score 1):

Simplest code would be

```
    if (bool1 || bool2 || bool3)
    {
        if (bool1)
            execute_bool1();
        if (bool2)
            execute_bool2();
        if (bool3)
            execute_bool3();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
```